# How to span \textit{} and \Large several lines in \author{}

Tags: line-breaking, titles, text-decorations

I would like to span `\textit{}` in several line in `\author{}` tag.

So far I know I can do this ( but here `\LARGE` will only affect the `Name`) :

```
% title
\title{\textbf{Cool title}}
\author{\LARGE Name\\
        \emph{University}\\
        \emph{Faculty}\\
        \emph{mail@mail.com}
        }
\date{}         % Do not print the date on the final paper!
\maketitle
```

But if I try to

```
\author{\LARGE{Name\\
        \emph{University\\ 
        Faculty\\ 
        mail@mail.com}
        }
        }
```

I get the following error :

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

./main.tex:60: Missing } inserted. [\maketitle]
./main.tex:60: Missing } inserted. [\maketitle]
./main.tex:60: Missing \cr inserted. [\maketitle]
./main.tex:60: Missing \cr inserted. [\maketitle]
./main.tex:60: Misplaced \cr. [\maketitle]
```

**EDIT**

```
\author{\itshape Name\\
        University\\ 
        Faculty\\ 
        mail@mail.com
        }
```

This would only affect `Name` also.

**EDIT**

I use following the `documentclass`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
```

Comment: The reason this happens, I *think*, is that internally LaTeX typesets the author in a tabular environment. That is, article.cls includes a definition of \maketitle which includes \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\@author\end{tabular} and so the font selection is "grouped" in the same way it is in any entry in a tabular. It is also why you get errors if you try to use e.g. \emph across lines. You would either need to redefine \maketitle or use a package which does so, I think. For example, you might look at the titling package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typesetting of the address takes place in a one column `tabular` environment, so

```
\emph{First line\\
second line}
```

is illegal as it would be in

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
\emph{First line\\
second line
\end{tabular}
```

The simplest remedy is to use the package `authblk`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\LARGE\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\normalsize\itshape}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}
\author{Name}
\affil{University\\
  Faculty\\
  email@uni.edu}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that internally LaTeX typesets the author in a tabular environment. That is, `article.cls` includes a definition of `\maketitle` which includes

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
\@author
\end{tabular}
```

and so the font selection is "grouped" in the same way it is in any entry in a tabular. It is also why you get errors if you try to use e.g. `\emph` across lines.

The `titling` package can be used to redefine elements of the `\maketitle` command. This example adds a little space beneath your name before typesetting your affiliation and email details. It defines a new command `\affiliation{}` to hold these details which does not use the tabular environment. It also builds the font shape selection into the redefinition of `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
  \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}
  \preauthor{\begin{center}
    \LARGE \lineskip 0.5em%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
  \postauthor{\end{tabular}\end{center}}
  \newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{%
    \gdef\affil{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
    \centering\itshape \affil\par}


% title
\title{Cool title}
\author{Name}
\affiliation{University\\
        Faculty\\
        mail@mail.com
        }
\date{}         % Do not print the date on the final paper!

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: Use of titling command to redefine aspects of \maketitle]

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this many times. I suggest you give up and do what I did: type 
`\LARGE` in each line again. If you need to change the line spacing,  you can always use `\renewcommand\baselinestretch` to whatever number you need.

Comment: Never give up if your desires are legal especially when you have this site up and running ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With any KOMA-Script class or with the package `scrextend` in combination with a standard class the following works since recently published version 3.12. So, in your situation with the latter case you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[extendedfeature=title]{scrextend} % adds several KOMA-Script
                                              % specific features
\addtokomafont{author}{\Huge\em} % KOMA-Script command

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Cool title}}
\author{\textup{Name}\\
        University\\
        Faculty\\
        mail@mail.com
       }
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The KOMA-Script specific titling feature must explicitly activated in `scrextend`.
Note, that I added `\Huge\em` (very huge just for making it more visible) for the whole entry and then switched back from emphasising only for the “Name”.

In all earlier KOMA-Script versions inclusive 3.11b the command `\addtokomafont{author}{…}` does not work. KOMA-Script also switches to the sans-serif font for all titles. If this is not appealing, one can add the following line before or after `\addtokomafont…`:

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```